# How to show my data in Unordered list format in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In my project I have four components those are  App, Componentc,

Componente, Componentf. Now I am trying to pass an Array from App to Componentf using Context API

I successfuly passed an Array, but the problem is in output the Array is showing like side by

side. but what I am expecting it has to show like Unordered list in html

Please help me to acheive this

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Componentc from './Componentc/Componentc';
// import './App.css';


export const UserContext = React.createContext()

const fruits = ['Apple','Orange','Banana','Grapes']

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={fruits}>
        <Componentc></Componentc>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Componentc

```
import React from 'react';
import './Componentc.css';
import Componente from '../Componente/Componente';

const Componentc = () => {
    return(
        <Componente></Componente>
    )
}

export default Componentc
```

This is Componente

```
import React from 'react';
import './Componente.css';
import Componentf from '../Componentf/Componentf';

const Componente = () => {
    return(
        <Componentf></Componentf>
    )
}

export default Componente
```

This is Componentf

```
import React from 'react';
import './Componentf.css';
import { UserContext } from '../App'

const Componentf = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <UserContext.Consumer>
                {
                    user => {
                        return <div className='d-block'>{user}</div>
                    }
                }
            </UserContext.Consumer>
            <h1>Component F</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Componentf
```

Comment: Please provide a full description of the expected result and the actual one

Comment: Hi @MohamedELAYADI I am trying to pass an Array from one component to another component for this we will use props. But I am using Context API to pass an Array from one component to another component.

Comment: Yes I saw, but you are not treating the array from the context like an array

Comment: Also, you can use `React.useContext` to retrieve context value, its more significative

Comment: ok then what is the solution for this.

Comment: I will write you a codesandbox example with the code you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much @MohamedELAYADI

Comment: I updated my answer to add a codesandbox demo link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of your context is an array, but you are treating it like an object in the context consumer.

You only need to change `return <div className='d-block'>{user}</div>` by :

```
        {user => {
          return user.map(t => (
            <div key={t} className="d-block">
              {t}
            </div>
          ));
        }}
```

Although your variables should have meaningful names; I recommend changing the name of the user context and variable to be fruits.

Also, If you are using a recent react version (> 16.8), I also recommend that you use `React.useContext` API to receive values from context, code become more readable.

```
const Componentf = () => {
  const fruits = React.useContext(FruitContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {fruits.map(fruit => (
        <div key={fruit} className="d-block">
          {fruit}
        </div>
      ))}
      <h1>Component F</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-swanson-2uc7c)